# K8s nginx ingress path return 404

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to setup my services inside nginx ingress. In this case, I want to have a mail service along the path test.io/mail/. I make a request to test.io/mail/send_mail/ the response comes 404.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: test-backend
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: test.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /mail/
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: email-test
            port:
              number: 80
```

If I change the settings and remove the prefix, then everything will work.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: test-backend
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: test.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: email-test
            port:
              number: 80
```

How do I properly set the prefix?

Answer (score 0):

Please have ingress yaml as below to use "pathType: Prefix" instead of "pathType: Exact"

```
 rules:
  - host: test.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /mail/
        pathType: Prefix
```

Please refer [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types) for more details for

> pathType: Prefix

Answer (score 0):

Each path in an Ingress is required to have a corresponding [path type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). Paths that do not include an explicit pathType will fail validation.
The only supported wildcard character for the path field of an Ingress is the * character. The * character must follow a forward slash (/) and must be the last character in the pattern. For example, /, /foo/, and /foo/bar/* are valid patterns, but , /foo/bar, and /foo//bar are not.A more specific pattern takes precedence over a less specific pattern. If you have both /foo/ and /foo/bar/, then /foo/bar/bat is taken to match /foo/bar/.For more information about path limitations and pattern matching, see the [URL Maps documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map).

Suggestion :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: test-backend
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: test.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /mail/*
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: email-test
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: email-test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Additional reference doc :
[Refer1](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1120#issuecomment-322007251)
[Refer2](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services)